# How to add padding to 100% div in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I previously asked how to make a design akin to this, with a 100% height div and one below it with the same background but outside view:

[image: Design Mockup]

The answer seemed pretty straightforward, just add padding to the top div, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/s6wnavqc/

HTML:

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="bottom-div">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background {
  background: url('http://www.mixflavour.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Nature-Wallpaper-03.jpg');
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.bottom-div {
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

However, when I add Bootstrap the design completely breaks for unknown reasons! I mean, simply adding it does that, not even using any containers or rows. I figured this warranted its own thread, since the previous answer did correctly address my problem as stated.

Take a look at this fiddle to see the padding being completely ignored: http://jsfiddle.net/s6wnavqc/1/

Not even adding `!important` after works.

Does anyone know why and how to fix this? Do I have to use `calc` on the `height` instead? I'd rather not do that because it's not supported on some browsers.

Comment: why are you adding padding? if you remove the padding-bottom line your design/css works perfectly?

Comment: @shenku Wait, what? No, it doesn't. Not when I try it, at least. Remember that the bottom div should be outside the view, not inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `box-sizing:content-box` to `.background`. By default in bootstrap all elements are set to `box-sizing:border-box` which means padding is absorbed into height/width, not added to it.

From bootstrap:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Override:

```
.background {
    background: url('http://www.mixflavour.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Nature-Wallpaper-03.jpg');
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: That's what the change is! Thanks a lot! I'm guessing there are drawbacks to this when it comes to Bootstrap's grid system but it should work for my purposes.

Comment: Bootstrap is not set in stone, it's very reasonable and appropriate to override this sort of thing if you need to. Now you understand box-sizing!